# Replacement of Interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have some market place classes that interact with their systems like Ebay, Amazon etc.

I want to make these classes define some mandatory functions such as createProduct, updateProduct, getCategories, getOrders.

Obviously these marketplace requires different format of data and so my functions are requiring different types and numbers of parameters in each class.

For example

## Ebay

```
public function createProduct($product, $multi)
```

## Amazon

```
public function createProduct(array $products, $multi, $variations)
```

In such case my i cannot implement the `MarketplaceInterface` as it breaks my code.

But I have to make these functions implementations mandatory too. 
What other ways I can achieve in PHP ?

Comment: check adapter or proxy pattern

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A usual way to resolve this kind of problem is to define an `optionsResolver` which is passed to each one of your class in order to be initialized.

```
$optionsResolver->setRequiredOptions(array('products', 'multi', 'variations'));
```

Then you pass your arguments as an array of options instead (this way you can keep your interface):

```
public function createProduct($options)
```

You can validate your options using something like:

```
$optionsResolver->resolve($options);
```

To see a full example of implementation, take a look at [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html).

---

**Example:**

```
class Ebay implements MarketPlaceInterface
{
    // ...

    public function createProduct(array $options = array())
    {
        $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
        $resolver
            ->setRequired(array('product', 'multi'))
            ->setAllowedTypes('product', 'string')
            ->setAllowedTypes('multi', 'boolean')
            ->setDefaults(array('multi' => true))
        ;

        // Add default values.
        // Check for required fields.
        // Check allowed types.
        // Throw an exception if the options have a wrong format.
        $options = $resolver->resolve($options);

        // Do the creation here.
    }
}

class Amazon implements MarketPlaceInterface
{
    // ...

    public function createProduct(array $options = array())
    {
        $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
        $resolver
            ->setRequired(array('products', 'multi', 'variations'))
            ->setAllowedTypes('products', 'array')
            ->setAllowedTypes('multi', 'boolean')
            ->setAllowedTypes('variations', 'array')
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'products' => array(),
                'multi' => true
            ))
        ;

        $options = $resolver->resolve($options);

        // Do the creation here.
    }
}
```

You can also set the behaviour in an abstract class or in a class manipulating the market place objects. Here is the case of an abstract class with a GOF's design pattern [template method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern):

```
abstract class AbstractMarketPlace implements MarketPlaceInterface
{
    // ...

    public function createProduct(array $options = array())
    {
        $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
        $this->setResolver($resolver);
        $options = $resolver->resolve($options);

        $this->doCreateProduct($options)
    }

    abstract protected function setResolver(OptionsResolver $resolver);

    abstract protected function doCreateProduct(array $options);
}

class Ebay extends AbstractMarketPlace
{
    // ...

    protected function setResolver(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setRequired(array('product', 'multi'))
            ->setAllowedTypes('product', 'string')
            ->setAllowedTypes('multi', 'boolean')
            ->setDefaults(array('multi' => true))
        ;
    }

    protected function doCreateProduct(array $options)
    {
        // Do the creation here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that hide the arguments from the method signature?

Comment: There is no point in trying to standardize an interface with variable arguments.  You won't be able to do it for all upcoming possibilities. Using a pattern "options" is one popular way to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: I have given it some more thought now, but I honestly cannot see how this would be a nice solution. I don't see what you gain by doing it this way. But I see you lose a lot.

Comment: Now.. 6 month passed. I'm in the middle of some calls. I see something like `createProduct($options)`, aaand.. and what? What are those options? Can I understand the code from the line it's written directly, or I should: `1.` find declaration of those _$options_ ; `2.` find declaration of that _createProduct_ ; `3.` match each array key with that method signature ; `4.` finally find that in some other implementation, array keys and/or structure is different, and because of that - `5.` go to the _createProduct_ method **body** and read that code? Am I the only one here thinking that it smells?

Comment: @AlmaDo The definition of this options with their types and default values (the  initialization of the `optionsResolver`) must be set in the class which implements `createProduct($options)` (or in a linked configuration file). If you know how to standardize an interface with different arguments for each implementor I would like you to post your way here. This would interest a lot of people!

Comment: @JoeWatkins You're totally right that this does not mean it is the best solution. However, this is a common way to do it and many developpers know this solution.

Comment: @PeeHaa I think it would be better for the asker you explain your point of view like Alma Do did. Your comment is not really participating to the debate because there is no argument inside it.

Comment: @AlmaDo I did not invent this pattern but I used it a lot and see a lot of people (in the open source community) using it. It is easy to understand, scalable and maintenable if you use it as you should.

Comment: So then either you are misusing/misunderstanding it or people whom you saw using it were doing it wrong. No matter how's implemented, the scenario I described is completely real and it will be a big issue once you'll spot stuff like that in a project with at least ~50k LoC

Comment: @Gnucki my first comment explains my POV

Comment: @AlmaDo If you don't know me, all I can do is to tell you to look at the link I gave at the end of my answer and search for real implementations. Some of the biggest and most used javascript codes use options even without an options resolver (options are only explained in a documentation). I don't like it but these codes are used in many big applications without "big issues".

Comment: @PeeHaa The solution to keep the signature is to not use an interface and make a high coupling between the market place classes and the classes using it with a nice switch case. I let you choose the better solution!

Comment: @AlmaDo * I wanted to say "If you don't believe me".

Comment: @Gnucki You have some easy example for this ? I am trying to understand the point but i would be very thankful to you if you can provide a short code example keeping in consideration my scenario. Symfony 2 documentation going above my head ! Thanks

Comment: @RaheelKhan I tried to apply the real implementation of Symfony2 on your example. I did not specify any namespace or use. Tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: @Gnucki Much clear, So the $optionResolver->resolve($options) will return error if any discrepancy in the arguments passed ?

Comment: It's exactly that! I added some comments in my code to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Gnucki Thanks bro .. Making sense to me :)

Comment: Glad I could help you!